# SwiftUI each item displays it own detailView when it is selected in a list

Tags: swift, xcode, listview, swiftui

I'm trying to make each item display it own detailView in a list using SwiftUI. But for now, I got stuck because it only display the same detailView for any item. Would anyone know how to do that?
This is the code I have for now:

```
 struct PastryListView: View {
@State private var isShowingDetailView = false

@State private var selectedPastry : Pastry?

@State private var selection: Int? = nil
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
    NavigationView {
        
        List(MockData.pastries) { Pastry in
            HStack {
                Image(Pastry.image)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 180, height: 200)
                VStack {
                    Text(Pastry.name)
                        .font(Font.custom("DancingScript-Regular", size: 30))
                        .fontWeight(.medium)
                       
                }
                .padding(.leading)
            }
        
            .onTapGesture {
                selectedPastry = Pastry
                isShowingDetailView = true
            
            }
           
          
           
                    
        }
        .navigationTitle(" Pastries")
    }
        
        if isShowingDetailView {                Pastry2DetailView(isShowingDetailView2: $isShowingDetailView, pastry: MockData.samplePastry2)


        }
      
    }
}  }
```

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to achieve what you want, this is just one way:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            PastryListView()
        }
    }
}

struct Pastry: Identifiable {
   var id: String = UUID().uuidString
   var name: String
   var image: UIImage
}

struct PastryListView: View {
    @State private var pastries: [Pastry] = [
        Pastry(name: "pastry1", image: UIImage(systemName: "globe")!),
        Pastry(name: "pastry2", image: UIImage(systemName: "info")!)]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(pastries) { pastry in
                NavigationLink(destination: PastryDetailView(pastry: pastry)) {
                    HStack {
                        Image(uiImage: pastry.image)
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
                        VStack {
                            Text(pastry.name)
                                .font(Font.custom("DancingScript-Regular", size: 30))
                                .fontWeight(.medium)
                        }
                        .padding(.leading)
                    }
                }
            }.navigationTitle(" Pastries")
        }.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}

struct PastryDetailView: View {
    @State var pastry: Pastry
    var body: some View {
        Text(" " + pastry.name + " ")
    }
}
```